# PHP and Xpath (Xpath if node empty then set value as '0')

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

Hi all im struggling with an XPath query, I want the query to return a '0' value when it has found nothing. Here is my code so far:

`$query = $xpathvar->query('//DataStatistics/report');
         foreach($query as $result){
        echo "$result->length";`

It just returns blank at the moment, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the length of the `$query` itself (if there's no `length`, the loop never runs):

```
$query = $xpathvar->query('//DataStatistics/report');
echo $query->length;
```